# Create event, retrieve the event ID, and assign to a column. onEdit delete the event, and resubmit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create event in calendar, and then retrieve the event ID, so user can later edit it if they need to. This is the create event script, eventID will be saved in column 13:

```
      function createEvent(request){
  var event = request.calendar.createEvent(
    "Booked",
    request.date,
    request.endTime
    );
  var formRes = FormApp.openById('1pULKXVNg9GSUSA_mhVSUHMG7MBP3GvSgHmqrAnyhLvo'); 
  var sheetRes = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Hokusei 41');
  var data = sheetRes.getDataRange().getValues();
  var eventIdCol = 13;
  var responses = formRes.getResponses();
  var timestamps = [], ids = [], resultids = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
    ids.push(responses[i].event.getId());
}
  for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
    resultids.push([data[j][0]?ids[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:'']);
    }
    sheetRes.getRange(2, eventIdCol, resultids.length).setValues(resultids);
    }
```

However, I still couldn't get the ID from the code above, is there any other way to retrieve the ID and then assign in to a column in sheet?

This function will also detect conflict within the calendar to prevent overlapping booking.

```
function getConflicts(request){
  var conflicts = request.calendar.getEvents(request.date, request.endTime);
  if (conflicts.length > 0) {
    request.status = "Conflict";
  } else {
    request.status = "Approve";
  }
}
```

Also I have added onEdit() function, in which it will delete the event by ID, and then resubmit it again.  This is the piece of the code:

```
 function updateEvent(e) {
  var editedRow = e.range.getRow();
  var editedData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(editedRow, 12).getValues()[0];
  var eventId = editedData[0];
  var event = CalendarApp.getEventById();
  for (var i=0; i<e.length;i++){
    var ev = e[i];
    ev.deleteEvent();
    break;
  };
}
```

This is the main function onSubmit():

```
 function main(){
  var request = new Submission(lastRow);
  getEndTime(request);
  getConflicts(request);
  draftEmail(request);
  if (request.status == "Approve") updateCalendar(request);
  sendEmail(request);
}
```

However, when someone try to edit its own submission his/her previous order will still have conflict with their own submission. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought of doing the request to create the event inside a function as a standalone one and then get the ID from the [response](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#response)?

Comment: Hi Kessy thanks for the reply. I have a single function that will create event and another function that will detect time conflict...should I make them into one function?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `event.getId()` gets the event ID with a console.log? For what I see the responses array does not have the id because you are not using the response from creating the event that is the ' event ' var.

Comment: Actually I found out that if you want to use the ID, you need to get rid of "@google.com" part. This piece of code works like charm .getId().split('@')[0];

Comment: What do you mean by that? If solved, can you post the solution so more people can benefit from it?

Comment: Actually I solved the issue yesterday. I posted the solution but for some reason it is hidden. Will post again later.

Comment: Hey, please when possible, post the solution you found. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Kessy, honestly i am still struggling with this calendar event issue, so I didn't post the whole solution. But I just posted solution for the ID part at least.

Answer (score 1):

The problem before was caused by the fact that event ID can only be used if you get rid of the @google.com in the end...one way is to use this piece of code:

```
  var newEvent = calendar.createEvent("booked", request.date, request.endTime);
  var newEventId = newEvent.getId().split('@')[0];
```

And then to delete the event using the id, just use this piece of code:

```
 var eventEditId = calendar.getEventSeriesById(/*cell in which ID is stored*/);
  eventEditId.deleteEventSeries();
```